# Chamar função Javascript pelo Java (Webview android)

Tags: javascript, java, android, webview

Estou com uma dúvida simples de entender porém ainda não encontrei solução.
Tenho um `Webview` na minha `MainActivity` onde é carregado um WebSite responsivo que criei, nesse WebSite tenho um carrinho de compras que ao clicar nele abre uma `div` com os itens do usuário, e no topo direito da `div` um botao com um 'X' que ao ser clicado chama uma funçao `fechaCarrinho()` em `javascript`.

O problema é que quando ao pessoa está no `android` (WebView) ela clica no botão voltar do celular e o aplicativo fecha. Queria que ao clicar em voltar (no botão do celular) chamasse a função `fechaCarrinho()` da pagina Web, como faço isso?

Obrigado desde já.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Existem duas formas

### Protocolo `javascript:`

Pode executar a sua função assim:

```
webView.loadUrl("javascript:fechaCarrinho()");
```

### WebView.evaluateJavascript

Ou pode usar o [**WebView.evaluateJavascript**](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/WebView.html#evaluateJavascript(java.lang.String,%20android.webkit.ValueCallback%3Cjava.lang.String%3E)), o qual lhe permitirá até mesmo pegar o `return ...;` que será executado no próprio WebView:

> Requer no minimo a [API 19](http://API%20level%2019), se for inferior não irá funcionar

```
webView.evaluateJavascript(javascript, new ValueCallback<String>()
{
    @Override
    public void onReceiveValue(String value)
    {
        //Pega o valor do return de "fechaCarrinho" se você deseja
        Log.d(tag, value);
    }
});
```

Comment: Nossa @Guilherme, tava esperando um bicho de sete cabeças aqui kkkk vlew vou fazer uns testes depois e digo se deu certo.

Comment: Tudo bem @BrunoRomualdo ? Deu certo?

Comment: Opa desculpa amigo tava com problemas no pc por isso demorei pra testar e acabei esquecendo, mas deu certinho sim obrigado pela resposta.